# billing clients for google api's

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Questions regarding billing for Google API's or more specifically the places and maps Google API's.

We have an app which is part of a SAAS package. When clients use our Software we have maps and place's API built it, however we want to offset the cost of the bill using these API's to that particular client using the software.

Currently we have a single Google Project we created and enabled the API's on our own google account however this means we will foot the bill as its using our token.

Can clients somehow connect to our google project etc or do we simply need them to create their own google project and pass that token through? Is there a streamlined approach that covers this...

Answer (score 0):

When we did for our multi tenant application we did create only one google project and billing was getting accumulated into a single account. We looked at what you're talked about but since google does not allow to bill separately without having separate google project. Google API billing works on google project id. We decided to bill our clients separately and handled all calls to Places API on a single google project.

Long story short - it was not easy to have our clients connect to our project without having them create their own google project we ended up with one google api project.

edit: also missed another important point - Google My Business API needed whitelisting for each project id so it was another reason to keep it as a single project

Answer (score 0):

Passing the token to the application is a probably very bad idea and will result in a security risk for your client and their token if it is intercepted.

As a developer for the client they should create a token on their account and then they will be charged.  They can then give it to you as the developer for use.  This is however a gray area as technically you are not allowed to share your tokens with anyone [TOC](https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/11/subject-changes-to-google-apis-terms-of.html) However i believe that client and developer relationship should be secure enough for sharing the token.

Ideally you should give the client the code they can then use their own token and run the application themselves.